# Dynamic styling in list render

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm having a hard time trying to set a dynamic width to 3 different elements in a list

The idea here is to fill a bar so the sum of the 3 divs length take 100%. [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nabhc.png)

The 3 divs have completely random values that I get from their own length (there are arrays).

I'm trying to set a width with the `calculateWidth` function, which I call 3 times to get the 3 different sizes.

Note : I receive all the props from Redux.

Here is the simplified code :

```
function calculateWidth(x, y, z) {
   let value;
   let sum = x + y + z;
   value = (100 * x)/sum;
   return value
}

let commentsList =
    article &&
    article.comments.map((comment, index) => (

      <Link to={`/${comment.slug}`} key={index}>

   {calculateWidth(comment.rating.good.length, comment.rating.good.length, comment.rating.good.length)}
   {calculateWidth(comment.rating.average.length, comment.rating.good.length, comment.rating.bad.length)}
   {calculateWidth(comment.rating.bad.length, comment.rating.average.length, comment.rating.good.length)}


        <div className="comment-regular" style={}> {comment.rating.good.length}</div>
        <div className="comment-regular" style={}> {comment.rating.average.length}</div>
        <div className="comment-regular" style={}> {comment.rating.bad.length}</div>  

      </Link>                      
));
```

The `calculateWidth` function will give me the correct percentage for the 3 divs.

How can I access this value and put it in each div style attribute ? 
Something like `style={width:`$(something)` + %}

Thank you

Comment: this should work:  `style={{width: `${someWidth}%`}}`

Comment: style={{width:`\`${something}%\``}} should work.

Comment: None of these works sadly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inline styles are represented as javascript objects in jsx.

Make 3 variables say for example width1,width2 and width3 use a template literal in the object as the value for the 'width' key.

```
<div className="comment-regular" style={{'width' : `${width1}%`}}>
```

Change your map function to get those three values and then return jsx.

```
article.comments.map((comment, index) => {

const width1 = calculateWidth(comment.rating.good.length, comment.rating.good.length, comment.rating.good.length)
 const width2=calculateWidth(comment.rating.average.length, comment.rating.good.length, comment.rating.bad.length)
  const width3=calculateWidth(comment.rating.bad.length, comment.rating.average.length, comment.rating.good.length)
return (

      <Link to={`/${comment.slug}`} key={index} >


        <div className="comment-regular" style={{'width' : `${width1}%`}}> {comment.rating.good.length}</div>
        <div className="comment-regular" style={{'width' : `${width2}%`}}> {comment.rating.average.length}</div>
        <div className="comment-regular" style={{'width' : `${width3}%`}}> {comment.rating.bad.length}</div>  

      </Link>                      
)});
```

Comment: The function is working but literal values are placed where the function is called, I get "100 0 0". The style is not applied on the `comment-regular` div though...

Comment: Updated the answer to modify the signature of you map function..it will first get those three values and then return jsx.

Answer (score 0):

Expressions in `{}`, that are put loosely in JSX, return value into the void and they are not used anywhere. You should call it inside your `style={}`.

I couldn’t help myself to destructure a bit which allowed me to see that in the first case you’re passing three times good. Operating on calls like `calculateWidth(comment.rating.good.length, comment.rating.good.length, comment.rating.good.length)` is error prone because mind needs to read through much more text.

```
function calculateWidth(x, y, z) {
    return (100 * x) / (x + y + z);
}

let commentsList =
    article &&
    article.comments.map(({ comment: { slug, rating: { good: { length: goodCount }, average: { length: averageCount }, bad: { length: badCount } } } }, index) => (
        <Link to={`/${slug}`} key={index}>
            <div className="comment-regular" style={{ width: calculateWidth(goodCount, badCount, averageCount) + '%' }}> {goodCount}</div>
            <div className="comment-regular" style={{ width: calculateWidth(averageCount, goodCount, badCount) + '%' }}> {averageCount}</div>
            <div className="comment-regular" style={{ width: calculateWidth(badCount, averageCount, goodCount) + '%' }}> {badCount }</div>  
        </Link>                      
    ));
```